# Code in function won't run whilst in function. Works if written outside function

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

Have some issues with my current homework.

The code inside (while loop) function startGame() won't run when written inside the function. If I remove the function declaration it works as intended. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;
let i = 0;

function startGame() {
  while (i < 5) { // This part wont run when used inside function (){}
    playRound();
    i += 1;
  }
}
/*
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  playRound();
}
*/

/* NOTE TO SELF:
Can't do call to function before declaring variables. 
Since they then would be undefined during runtime. */

function playRound() {
  playerSelection = prompt();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  if (playerSelection.trim() === computerSelection.trim()) {
    console.log("Round is Equal")

  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissor" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Scissor") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissor") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissor" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  }
}

function computerPlay() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1:
      randomNumber = "Rock";
      return randomNumber;
    case 2:
      randomNumber = "Scissor";
      return randomNumber;
    case 3:
      randomNumber = "Paper"
      return randomNumber;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke `startGame` function:

```
startGame()
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow sorry for taking up your time with this. Obvious i have spent too many hours reading / programming today..
Feel free to delete this question (anyone with right to do so - i tried but it didn't let me)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an initial call to `startGame()` functions do not run on their own.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;
let i = 0;

function startGame() {
  while (i < 5) { // This part wont run when used inside function (){}
    playRound();
    i += 1;
  }
}

startGame();

/*
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  playRound();
}
*/

/* NOTE TO SELF:
Can't do call to function before declaring variables. 
Since they then would be undefined during runtime. */

function playRound() {
  playerSelection = prompt();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  if (playerSelection.trim() === computerSelection.trim()) {
    console.log("Round is Equal")

  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissor" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Scissor") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissor") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Scissor" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    playerScore += 1;
    console.log("Player score is:" + " " + playerScore + " " + "Player wins round");

  } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    computerScore += 1;
    console.log("Computer score is:" + " " + computerScore + " " + "Computer win round");

  }
}

function computerPlay() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1:
      randomNumber = "Rock";
      return randomNumber;
    case 2:
      randomNumber = "Scissor";
      return randomNumber;
    case 3:
      randomNumber = "Paper"
      return randomNumber;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created a function called startGame() but your are not calling it anywhere which is why it's not running within the function.

Just like the way your calling playRound() within your loop, you also have to call startGame() for code in it to run.